# Way to limit ssh-key to multiple commands?

Tags: ssh, freebsd

Is it possible to limit particular ssh-key to multiple commands?

Example:

```
command="ls some/folder","scp some/folder other/folder" ssh-rsa ABCD...
```

Comment: For me looks like XY problem. What is the generic/big idea?

Comment: The idea is to provide X ssh-key only to this two commands ( ls and scp ). The workaround is easy, but I wanted to know if comma separated way is possible here.

Comment: How should the server know which command to use?

Comment: They are sequential. I don't really need the server to know, he will use what is given. Ls and then scp. But I think only one command is allowed.

Comment: So you want `ls…; scp …`? Why is this a problem?

Comment: Put them in a script and allow that script?

Comment: Personally: test it. I would not trust any documentation on such limits. They tend to be outdated (and also our experience: we keep in memory just the old lower limits)